# Accessing SQLite database values in an activity android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I am working on a book app and I save the book contents in SQLite database which I placed in my assets folder in Android Studio. But now I want to retrieve the values in the database in an activity in my app, but with the method I have seen online I can only retrieve one value from the database.

Please bear with me because I don't know if I'm properly explaining what I want but let me show the code so I can explain better.

```
    listItem = new ArrayList<>();
    database = new Database(this);

  //  song = String.valueOf(database.getChapter());

    SQLiteDbHelper dbHelper = new SQLiteDbHelper(this);
    dbHelper.openDatabase();
    modelArrayList  = dbHelper.getDetails();

    adapter = new SongAdapter(modelArrayList);

    chapFind = findViewById(R.id.chap_find);
    chapGo = findViewById(R.id.chap_go);

    String tokenID = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    Model count = modelArrayList.get(0);
    final String chap = String.valueOf(count.getIds());
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,chap,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    mDatabasse = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Token");

    chapGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String num = chapFind.getText().toString();
            if (num.equals(chap)){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"very good!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"very bad",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

So what I am trying to do with this code - is to get user input of the chapter they would like to read. Then - check if that chapter exists in the database and if it does app will send user to another activity where it will fully display the content of that chapter

Comment: The database in the assets folder is part of your apk file which is read-only. You can't modify it. You must copy the database from the assets folder to the device/emulator first and then access it.

Comment: can you show how to do this?